# Transformer is not a constructor error while updating react native sdk version from 0.61.5 to 0.64.0

Tags: javascript, react-native, metro-bundler

[image]I am getting **Transformer is not a constructor** error after upgrading my react native version to latest.
My metro-react-native-babel-preset version is 0.64.0
Please help me with a solution

Answer (score 13):

Are you by any chance including the `react-native-fs` package (v2.17.0)? That package has an internal dependency of an older `metro` and `metro-config` (v0.51.1) and my project is resolving to that version instead of the latest.

Try running `npm ls metro-config` to see which version is resolving (i.e. the one at the top of the list that comes back). I had to force-install both `metro` and `metro-config` like so:

```sh
npm i -D metro@0.64.0 metro-config@0.64.0 --force
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, just like @cr0ybot said, it was related with an incompatible version of metro-config.

Steps to solve:

1. `yarn list metro-config` (it lists all packages that depends on metro-config).
2. If you have more than one version installed, try to discover which package is depending on.
3. Upgrade the package that depends on the old version of metro-config

> If `yarn list` is not helping much, you will need to have a look on your `yarn.lock` to figure out the dependencies.

In my case the problem was the `react-native-community/cli`, but can be any package.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but on my react-native app I accidentally bumped my react-native version to 0.64.1 and saw this. Reverting back to the version I was using previously (0.63.2) solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this can happen with the incompatibility of versions of `react` and `metro-config`.

Please do check the version of `metro-config` being expected by running `npm ls metro-config`, this will list as shown below

[image]

And then force update using `npm i -D metro@x.x.x metro-config@x.x.x --force` to the version being expected

Answer (score -2):

Fixed by changing the metro.config.js file to

```
 module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```