# Metro error 'TypeError: Transformer is not a constructor' during codepush; unique to my machine

Tags: node.js, npm, metro-bundler, code-push

I last ran a successful codepush from my machine 2.5 weeks ago.
I attempted to run a codepush yesterday and ran into the following error:

```
Welcome to Metro!
          Fast - Scalable - Integrated
error index.js: Transformer is not a constructor.
TypeError: Transformer is not a constructor
    at getTransformer
```

which I believe to be related to this stackoverflow question: [Transformer is not a constructor error while updating react native sdk version from 0.61.5 to 0.64.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66967279/transformer-is-not-a-constructor-error-while-updating-react-native-sdk-version-f)

There have been no recent package changes which would have caused this.
My colleagues are able to successfully run the codepush command from the same commit on their machines.

I have tried checking out the last commit I was able to run a codepush for 2.5 weeks ago, and today I get the 'Transformer is not a constructor' error.

I have tried recloning the repo, and I still get the 'Transformer is not a constructor' error.

I have checked that my node and npm versions match those of my colleagues.
I have checked that I get the same results as my colleagues when I run `npm ls metro` and `npm ls metro-config`.
I have tried repeatedly clearing and re-installing npm packages, running npm cache clean, and restarting my computer.

It seems like there is something about my development environment which is different to those of my colleagues, and whatever this difference is, it has occurred sometime in the last 2 weeks. I am not aware of any change having been made.

Can anybody suggest any further diagnostic steps I can take to get to the root of this problem?